# Windows - Port 4200 is being used by System - Angular project

Tags: angular, windows

I know there are many questions already asked on SO and elsewhere regarding port 4200 already being in use when attempting to run an Angular project. However, the issue that a couple of my teammates are running into isn't just that the port is already in use, but it's in use by the System process... so killing the process probably isn't an option even if Windows allowed us to do so.

Normally I'd just run a project on a different port but in this case our project has a ton of back end dependencies configured to have our app being run on 4200. Not ideal obviously, and we have attempted to change these dependencies, but are having issues there as well.

**Question is: How can we change this System process to use a different port other than 4200?**

I've tried to do some further investigation as to why port 4200 is being used but I haven't had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Attempting to run the Angular project:
[image]

Running a netstat, 4200 is being used by PID 4:

[image]

PID 4 appears to be System when I look it up in Task Manager:

[image]

Comment: Q: If there's any way we can have System use a different port than 4200, that would be awesome.  A: Horse.  Cart.  Switch places.  Change your *ANGULAR* listener port.  EXAMPLE: `ng serve --port 4401`

Comment: Normally I'd just run a project on a different port but in this case our project has a ton of back end dependencies configured to have our app being run on 4200.

Comment: Seems like this would help: https://superuser.com/a/1248422/1150194